# Stack Overflow design broken in Firefox Mobile

Tags: support, design, mobile-web, mobile-firefox

Is there an issue when Stack Overflow is used with Firefox on Mobile devices? A few weeks ago the design suddenly changed, now it looks pretty much like the desktop version, see screenshot. The nice and useful mobile theme disappeared.

Of course, in my Firefox settings I did **not** set "Show desktop version" - anyway there is almost no difference.

With the Chrome browser it looks much better (like it was looking in Firefox earlier times), see the second screenshot.

**Firefox Screenshot:**

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

**Chrome Screenshot:**

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

Comment: In the page footer, you can switch between "full site" and "mobile".